# Direct Link to Child Route in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to implement a basic list with details in Angular 4.

I have the following routes:

```
{
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: DetailComponent,
      }
}
```

I have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `ListComponent`. Everything works fine when you click a link in the `ListComponent` to the child route. However, when you enter the link directly into the browser, I get the following error:

> Cannot find primary outlet to load

I thought that when you navigate to a child route, it automatically loads the parent component. Am I missing something? How do I implement it so that I can also navigate to the URL directly?

---

**Update:** Here's the ListComponent file:

```
<div *ngIf="!loadingData">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let listItem of lists">
            <a href="#">{{ listItem.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: what does your `index.html` have? And can you post the code where you have the router-outlet in the list component? Is there a selector there that shouldn't be?

Comment: We had a similar issue on our server, but only in production when node.js was serving the app.  Does this work in angular-cli in development and not in production, or both places?

Comment: @0mpurdy I've added the ListComponent file. I've just realised that it's the ngIf which is causing the router-outlet to not be displayed. If you answer the question I'll mark is as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ListComponent`  has an `*ngIf` that when it resolves to false, means the `<router-outlet>` is not in the DOM, giving you the error. You should move it outside of the `*ngIf`

```html
<div *ngIf="!loadingData">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let listItem of lists">
            <a href="#">{{ listItem.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

What there might be over here is when you route to the child component using the parent link the low data will be present and as the Router outlet is inside an ngif it will get populated.

But now when you hit the URL directly with the child link the if block will have data and the child route is not shown